# Session based authentication or token based authentication which one to use?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I am developing a full stack MEAN(MongoDB,Express JS,Angular JS,Node JS) application/service and implementing the Authorization and Authentication part.I have also planning to develop an android and ios application for the same service,
Regarding this I have studied a lot of blogs and websites how to implement Authorization and Authentication and what are the ways to do that.

After that I find that there are 2 ways to implement that:

1. Session based Authorization and Authentication
2. Token based Authorization and Authentication

Both of them have there pros and cons still i want some suggestions and open notes on that which one to implement and why?

If anybody have good links where i can read the case studies for which one to implement and how to do that please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Session Authentication vs. Token Authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication)

Comment: Thanks  for replying !